# Should Ordered and Unordered Parallel Collections have Different Types in C#?

Tags: c#, collections, plinq, parallel-processing

Using PLINQ C# parallel queries are ordered or unordered depending on how you construct them. There is some information [on MSDN here regarding order preservation in PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677.aspx).

I find this confusing and tricky to manage. In my mind collections where the order is significant are *sequences* and collections where order is not significant are *bags* (or if there are no duplicates, then they might be *sets*).

The operations on bags and sequences are different, and have different complexity characteristics especially when implemented as parallel algorithms.

In other words I think that ordered and unordered collections should be different types, and that this would simplify things. Is there a reason why everything in PLINQ is unified as simply a "ParallelQuery()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason why everything in PLINQ is unified as simply a "ParallelQuery()"

It's simpler. I suppose 2 types would have been possible but at some considerable expense. And would it be any easier to use?

When you process a sequence in Parallel then by default you give up Order. You ought to be aware that re-establishing sequence is expensive and that it should require some  extra steps.

But when you need it, adding an `.AsOrdered()` seems much less of a pain than copying (!) your data to another collection first.